# Bulk fix missing semicolons that JSHints finds in project

Tags: javascript, command-line, gruntjs, jshint

I have a project of 100+ javascript files each with 1-5 missing semicolons according to JSHint (as a result multiple people working on the project with different conventions).

I'd like to bulk fix everything as it's not practical to fix each individually. I've found this: https://github.com/jshint/fixmyjs but I don't see a way only fix semicolons without 'fixing' other things (tabs -> spaces, for example).

Does anyone know of way to do this? I'm comfortable with the possibility that it might cause breakage/introduce bugs. I've look over the errors and they look pretty routine.

Comment: Introducing semicolons in the wrong places can cause some extremely weird, hard-to-find errors.

Comment: Most text editors can do this, especially in a way that lets you "review as you change"...

Comment: I use Sublime--how would I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I really hope you like this as a solution. Be vary careful that you verify with jshint again after you've fixed the issues. And out of curiosity, how did you manage to get so many broken javascript files?

```
#!/bin/sh
function fixFile {
  for i in `jshint $1 | grep -i "Missing semicolon" \
                      | sed -e 's/\([^0-9]*\)\([0-9]*\)\(.*$\)/\2/'`;
  do
    sed -i $1 -e $i's/\(\s*\)$/;/'
  done
}

fixFile $1
```

The above uses jshint to produce some error lines, greps them for the missing semicolon errors only, extracts the line number of each error, then seds the file in place on that line to remove any trailing whitespace and replace it with a semicolon.

The file...

```
var a = 5, c = 4

function helloWorld() {
  if (this == doesntmakesense)
    console.log('hello' + 'world');
}

console.log(a+c);
console.log('finished')
```

...becomes...

```
var a = 5, c = 4;

function helloWorld() {
  if (this == doesntmakesense)
    console.log('hello' + 'world');
}

console.log(a+c);
console.log('finished');
```

Where petty semantic errors are ignored, and only semicolons treated.

I'd save the bash script as something like `fixFile.sh` and then run `find . -name "*.js" -exec ./fixFile.sh {} \;`

But please commit beforehand. All commands are run at your own risk ;)

Comment: This is great. Thanks for taking the time! I'm not able to get it to work though. When I run it I get the following error: "sed: -i may not be used with stdin" a bunch of times (presumably for each file). Do you know a way around this?

Comment: What os are you on? the sed -i flag means modify the file in place. If you're on os x, use brew to install gnu-sed, then use gsed instead of sed. The gnu sed is much more capable anyway.

Comment: Thanks installing gnu-sed and using gsed in place of sed did the trick (I'm on OSX Mavericks). It did put some semicolons in weird places though causing a little breakage which I'm sorting. Nevertheless, I think this is the right answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Great! Happy to hear it. Thought it wouldn't be foolproof but if it means you've got half the work then it was worth it.

Comment: This doesn't work for one-liners like

`Connection.$on('load_page', function(e, msg){ $scope.load_page(msg) });`

where a semicolon is missing from the internal function.

Comment: Hi @dionyziz, that's not really a surprise - I didn't really expect it to be foolproof. This was only meant to deal with 90% of the missing semi-colons, but actually with your line above any JS parser would insert a semi-colon and would be fine anyway. Or you can use fixmyjs as suggested by Chris2M

Answer (score 11):

There is a safer way of adding missing semicolons than using regular expressions. Use the following steps to configure fixmyjs to only fix semicolons as originally asked by Evan:

1. **Install fixmyjs**

   `npm install fixmyjs -g`
2. **Create a fixmyjs config file `fixmyjs-config` with the following content**

   `{ "asi": false }`
3. **Run fixmyjs**

   `fixmyjs --config [fixmyjs-config] --legacy yourfile.js`

Reference: https://github.com/jshint/fixmyjs/issues/86

Answer (score 1):

Google Closure JS Linter has a program that comes with it, able to correct some of the more regular violations such as this one I believe, it's named `fixjsstyle` (python btw)